# Damage does not seem to apply to object?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a basic text adventure game and seem to have gotten stuck on applying damage to my characters. I am able to get the damage numbers but for some reason it does not seem to be affecting their health, does anyone have any suggestions?

```
function Person(firstName, lastName, hp, concious, str, def, agi, frc ) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName  = lastName;
    this.hp        = hp;
    this.concious  = concious;
    this.str       = str;
    this.def       = def;
    this.agi       = agi;
    this.frc       = frc;

    var sayName = function(p) {
        console.log(p.firstName);
    }

    this.attack = function(Person) {
        var attPow = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.str);
        var attSpe = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.agi);
        var defAtt = Math.floor(Math.random() * Person.def);
        var defAgi = Math.floor(Math.random() * Person.agi);
        console.log(attPow, attSpe, defAtt, defAgi);

        if (attPow > defAtt && attSpe > defAgi){
            return Person.hp -= attPow + attSpe - defAtt;
            console.log(Person.hp);
        } if(attPow < defAtt && attSpe < defAgi) {
            alert("You missed");
        } if (attPow < defAtt) {
            alert("He blocked you're attack");
        } if (attSpe < defAgi) {
            alert("He dodged you're attack");
        }
    }
};

var Angelo = new Person("Angelo", " ", 75, 50, 5, 5, 5, 5);
var boy    = new Person("boy","dead", 75,50,5,2,5,5);
Angelo.attack(boy);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by "the answer of Angel Politis". For your scenario you should be bundling up all your `if` statements into a block using the `else-if` keyword.

Your code is fine, it works but only on intermittent basis. Reason was because you are missing a specific case in the `if` block which you are not catering for. You will notice it when you add an `else` to your condition check.

```
if (attPow > defAtt && attSpe > defAgi){
  console.log("ATTACK!");
  return Person.hp -= attPow + attSpe - defAtt;
} else if(attPow < defAtt && attSpe < defAgi) {
  console.log("You missed");
} else if (attPow < defAtt) {
  console.log("He blocked you're attack");
} else if (attSpe < defAgi) {
  console.log("He dodged you're attack");
}
else {
  console.log("????");
}

var Angelo = new Person("Angelo", " ", 75, 50, 5, 5, 5, 5);
var boy    = new Person("boy","dead", 75,50,5,2,5,5);
console.log("before HP:" + boy.hp);
Angelo.attack(boy);
console.log("after HP:" + boy.hp);
```

On occurence where boy's HP is untouched. You will see this;

**Output:**

> before HP:75
>   0 1 0 1 
>   ???? 
>   after HP:75

Notice how the `console.log("????")` got triggered? It means you are missing a scenario that you are not handling. Recommend you to dump the values for `attPow`, `defAtt`, `attSpe` and `defAgi` variables for the `else` clause and see what you are missing.

Comment: Oh ok, I think i'm getting it. By dump you mean completely remove for the entire equation?

Comment: @l34lo1 - Dump means to print the value of the variables. :P Hope it helps. Let me know if you still have question. Will appreciate if you can mark this as answered by clicking on the tick beside my answer if I have helped you :o

Answer (score 0):

Without looking into detail, one obvious reason your code doesn't work is that the following part of your code is wrong:

```
if (attPow > defAtt && attSpe > defAgi){
    return Person.hp -= attPow + attSpe - defAtt;
    console.log(Person.hp);
} if(attPow < defAtt && attSpe < defAgi) {
    alert("You missed");
} if (attPow < defAtt) {
    alert("He blocked you're attack");
} if (attSpe < defAgi) {
    alert("He dodged you're attack");
}
```

---

To create a complete check, you have to chain these **`if`** statements in the following format:

```
if (attPow > defAtt && attSpe > defAgi){
    return Person.hp -= attPow + attSpe - defAtt;
    console.log(Person.hp);
} else if(attPow < defAtt && attSpe < defAgi) {
    alert("You missed");
} else if (attPow < defAtt) {
    alert("He blocked you're attack");
} else if (attSpe < defAgi) {
    alert("He dodged you're attack");
}
```